# What should the hreflang be for sites with more than 3 languages containing child pages?

Tags: seo, internationalization, language, hreflang

We've got a domain: `https://www.example.com/`

1. Right now the domain is pointing directly to the page. We are based in Germany. So actually the site should be directing to `https://www.example.com/de`, right?
2. We want to create a Spanish and a Italian version of it. let's start the the Spanish version `https://www.example.com/es`

Now do ALL of the hreflang-tag have to be included? (including the Italian version) or just the the Spanish version and the default German version? How would the href lang tags look like?

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/en/" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="hhttps://www.example.com/de/" hreflang="de" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/it/" hreflang="it" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/es" hreflang="es" />
```

So do ALL of these 4 have to be in ANY page?

3. Do they also have to be included in the child page?
4. I've watched a google tutorial (which you can find here: https://youtu.be/8ce9jv91beQ?t=567 )where someone tries to explain it. If you click here and open the video at 9:27 she says something about "canonical". So when do I have to use "alternate" and when "canonical"?